# in(std::cin) : What does it mean?

Tags: c++, stl, istream-iterator

In the first example of Boost, `in(std::cin)` is used. I think `in()` get an `istream` and create some kind of iterator. However, I could not find any C++ documentation that explain it in detail. Could you please help me to find one?

here is the copy and paste of the example from the Boost webpage:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   using namespace boost::lambda;
   typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;
   std::for_each(
   in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the typedef in the code:

```
typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;
```

Thus, `in(...)` is the same as `std::istream_iterator<int>(...)`: it's calling the constructor for that type. There is a 1-argument constructor which accepts a `std::istream`, creating an iterator that represents the current point in that stream; and a 0-argument constructor creating an iterator that represents the end of any given stream. So `std::for_each` will iterate over every value provided by `std::cin` from now until it runs out.

`std::istream_iterator<int>` takes a stream and provides an iterator over the `int`s in the stream, using `operator>>` to read them out of the stream.

> However, I could not find any C++ documentation that explain it in detail.

I don't know how you could possibly fail. I put `std::istream_iterator<int>` into Google and the first result was http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/istream_iterator.html which is pretty thorough, assuming you're already familiar with iterators. The next result is http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/istream_iterator/ which makes another attempt to explain things and is also fully detailed. Next comes http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/istream-iterator.html , similarly, which finally explicitly mentions `operator>>` instead of just talking about formatted I/O operations (which is what `operator>>` does). Next comes a page with some C++ example snippets, then a couple of StackOverflow questions where people were trying to do something similar, etc....

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I meant that I could not find any documentation for "in()".

Answer (score 9):

`in` is just a `typedef` for `std::istream_iterator<int>` so the example is just calling `std::for_each` on a "range" defined by the two temporary iterators: `std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin)` and `std::istream_iterator<int>()`.

A value-inititalized `istream_iterator` is just a universal "end" iterator for streams.

How `std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " "` works is more subtle. Because `_1` comes from the `boost::lambda` namespace, it ensures that the operators `*` and then `<<` from the `boost::lambda` namespace are used, rather than an `operator<<` that acts directly on a `std::ostream`. This way the whole expression becomes a *lambda* rather than (any part of it) being executed as a conventional expression at the call site of `for_each`.

Comment: I like how you _tried_ to condense the notion of a lambda in one paragraph there. I'm pretty sure that flies - whoosh - right over the top of the OP's head, but kudos for trying, and _not-failing_ in the process :) +1

Answer (score 4):

You defined it here:

```
typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;
```

Thus `in(std::cin)` is an iterator over integers, used by `std::for_each`, that reads from *stdin* (cin) and multiplies them by 3 and prints them out.